# Python try except finally invalid syntax error

Tags: python, exception, flask, finally

So I was trying to use this exception handling in python. I'm using python2.7 and flask for this. Also I am new to both python and flask so I must be doing something wrong here.

```
if test:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        print cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Users (email, password, firstname, lastname, home, gender, dob, bio, profile_Image) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}')".format(email, password, firstname, lastname, home, gender, dob, bio, photo_data))
        conn.commit()
        #log user in
        user = User()
        user.id = email
        flask_login.login_user(user)
        uid = getUserIdFromEmail(flask_login.current_user.id)
        today = str(date.today())
        print today
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print "Something Went wrong"
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('register'))
    print cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Album (uid, aname, adate, cover) VALUES ('{0}', 'default', '{1}', '{2}')".format(uid, today, photo_data))
    aid = getAIDfromAname('default', uid)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Photo (uid, aid, data, caption) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', 'profile')".format(uid,aid,photo_data))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Scoreboard (uid) VALUES ('{0}')".format(uid))
    conn.commit()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    return render_template('profile.html', firstname=firstname, message='Account Created!')

else:
    print "couldn't find all tokens"
    return render_template('register.html', message='Email Already Exists')
```

and then It gives me this error if I run the app

```
  File "app.py", line 540
finally:
      ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am wondering why it's giving me the error :/

Comment: Your indentation is off. The try/exept block is ended the outdented print below it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if test:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        print cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Users (email, password, firstname, 
lastname, home, gender, dob, bio, profile_Image) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', 
'{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}')".format(email, password, firstname, 
lastname, home, gender, dob, bio, photo_data))
        conn.commit()
        #log user in
        user = User()
        user.id = email
        flask_login.login_user(user)
        uid = getUserIdFromEmail(flask_login.current_user.id)
        today = str(date.today())
        print today
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print "Something Went wrong"
        print cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Album (uid, aname, adate, cover) VALUES ('{0}', 'default', '{1}', '{2}')".format(uid, today, photo_data))
        aid = getAIDfromAname('default', uid)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Photo (uid, aid, data, caption) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', 'profile')".format(uid,aid,photo_data))
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Scoreboard (uid) VALUES ('{0}')".format(uid))
        conn.commit()
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('register'))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    return render_template('profile.html', firstname=firstname, message='Account 
Created!'))

else:
    print "couldn't find all tokens"
    return render_template('register.html', message='Email Already Exists'
```

This would work. The indentation on the line "print cursor.execute" inside except block was incorrect.

Comment: the code after the `return` statement in the expectation block will never execute.

Comment: Thanks. Rookie mistake. Edited the code. Sorry, I must have looked through the entire code.